# Saving,updating,deleting data using Entity Framework using Grid

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hello i'm pretty new to EF and been trying some examples on EF.Normally i dont have any issues when working with one object,but what really wonders me is,how do you work with it when used with a grid such as XtraGrid from devexpress?

Normally i use a binding source to set the grid's data source to the context using:

```
     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (var context = new BeygirDataModeliContainer())
        {
            beygirBindingSource.DataSource = context.BeygirSet;
        }


    }
```

If change the grid and set the event to :

```
    using (var context = new BeygirDataModeliContainer())
        {

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        gridControl1.RefreshDataSource();
```

It simply does not change or update or actually do anyting to the database.
The examples might be off but is there a tutorial what could help me to move on using EF with grids and maybe model collections?

Regards.

Comment: You're creating a new context and saving the changes it has recorded, which is none. You should keep the context with the changes, then call `SaveChanges` on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your entity Context "alive".  A `using` block call `Dispose` everytime it is close.

```
using (var context = new BeygirDataModeliContainer())
{
    beygirBindingSource.DataSource = context.BeygirSet;
}//context.Dispose() is call here
```

You should try something like this.

```
BeygirDataModeliContainer context; 
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    context = new BeygirDataModeliContainer()        
    beygirBindingSource.DataSource = context.BeygirSet; 
}
private void ApplyButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    context.SaveChanges();
}

private void CancelButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    context.Dispose();  
    context = new BeygirDataModeliContainer()
    beygirBindingSource.DataSource = context.BeygirSet;
    gridControl1.RefreshDataSource();
}
```